# Compare two text files to find differences and output them to a new text file

Tags: python, io, compare, diff

I am trying to work on a simple data comparison text document. The goal is for the user to be able to select a file, search through this file for a certain parameter, then print those parameters into a new text document, after compare those parameters from the new text document with a text document that has the default parameters and then once they've been compared to print out the differences into a new text document.

I've created a simple flowchart to summarize this:

[image: FlowChart]

This is my current code. I am using the diff lib to compare the two files.

```
import difflib
from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog
import tkMessageBox
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text ="Configuration Inspector")
w.pack()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome", "This is version 1.00 of Configuration Inspector")
filename = askopenfilename() # Logs File
filename2 = askopenfilename() # Default Configuration
compareFile = askopenfilename() # Comparison File
outputfilename = askopenfilename() # Out Serial Number Configuration from Logs

with open(filename, "rb") as f_input:
    start_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Serial Number", "What is the serial number?")
    end_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("End Keyword", "What is the end keyword")
    reText = re.search("%s(.*?)%s" % (re.escape(start_token + ",SHOWALL"), re.escape(end_token)), f_input.read(), re.S)
    if reText:
        output = reText.group(1)
        fo = open(outputfilename, "wb")
        fo.write(output)
        fo.close()

        diff = difflib.ndiff(outputfilename, compareFile)
        print '\n'.join(list(diff))

    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Output", "Sorry that input was not found in the file")
        print "not found"
```

The result so far is that the program correctly searches through the file you select for it to search through, Then prints out the parameters it finds into a new Output Text file.

The issues arises when trying to compare the two files, the Default Data and the Output File.

When comparing the program will output the differences however, Since the Default Data File has different lines than the Output file it will only print out the lines that do not match rather than the Parameters that do not match. In other words lets say I have these two files:

Default Data Text File:

```
Data1 = 1
Data2 = 2
Data3 = 3
Data4 = 4
Data5 = 5
Data6 = 6
```

Output Data Text File:

```
Data1 = 1
Data2 = 2
Data3 = 8
Data4 = 7
```

So since Data3 and Data4 do Not Match the difference.txt file (The Comparison Output) should show that. For Example:

```
Data3 = 8
Data4 = 7
Data5 = 5
Data6 = 6
```

However it does not match or compare the lines, it just checks to see if there's a line in that space. So currently my Comparison output looks like this:

```
Data5 = 5
Data6 = 6
```

Any ideas on how I can make the comparison show everything that is difference between the file's parameters?

If you need any more details please let me know in the comments I will edit the original post to add more details.

Comment: Have you tried doing anything to compare them? I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: So the issue is that the Default Data file compares with the Output file. but since the parameters for Data3 and Data4 are different in both files it doesn't show that they're different. It ignores them and only reports/prints out the lines it Doesnt have.

Comment: It looks like you have an ini file. Have you tried using something like configparser to load in the files and then compare them from there?

Comment: No I have not, Ill look into Config Parser.

Comment: It looks like you want to print all the lines that are in either one of the files, but not the other.  If that is correct, it's easy to do, you don't need the difflib.  If you're trying to do something more complicated, please specify it.

Comment: @saulspatz in order words I wanna compare the parameters in both files and print out if its different from the default. So lets say Default Data File states that Data1 = 13, and that in my output file it says Data1 = 15. Obviously Data1 in the default is different from the output one. So I would like it to print out Data1 = 15. Since the output file is different from the Default file

Comment: Is what you are trying to do somehow different from what I suggested?  Is there ever a case that you will print a line that occurs in both files?  Is there ever a case when you will fail to print a line that is in one of the files but not the other?

Comment: @saulspatz I apologize I miss read your comment, what you suggested is to print out the line that are not in the Output.txt compared to Default.txt. Correct? My question is even though I can print out all the lines that appear in one but not the other Im looking to compare lines and print out the different lines. Because Output could have 4 lines in it and the Default could have 6 lines in it. While this does mean that yes Output is missing 2 lines compared to the Default. I dont want it to just print out the 2 missing lines but any other line that does not match.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me.  It seems to me that you want to print out all the lines that are in output.txt but not in default.txt and also all the line that are in default.txt but not in output.txt.  If this isn't correct, why not?  If I'm wrong, please give me a specific example.

Comment: @saulspatz I want to just print out the lines that do not match with the default. Rather than print out all the lines that are not in default. Say for example you need to check a text document that has parameters right. You load the text file into the program and the program will compare your uploaded txt file with the default configuration file, then it will tell you "Hey look Data3 is equal to 15 in your uploaded file but it should be equal to 13 since according to your default thats what it is." So it prints out Data3 = 15 to let the user know that, that parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do with `difflib.ndiff()`. That function takes two lists of strings, but you are passing it filenames.

Anyway, here's a short demo that performs the comparison that you want. It uses a `dict` to speed up the comparison process. Obviously, I don't have your data files, so this program creates lists of strings using the string `.splitlines()` method.

It goes through the default data list line by line.
If that data is not present in the output `dict`, then the default line is printed.
If a data key with that value is present in the output `dict`, then that line is skipped.
If the key is found but the value in the output `dict` is different to the default value, then a line with the key & output value is printed.

```
#Build default data list
defdata = '''
Data1 = 1
Data2 = 2
Data3 = 3
Data4 = 4
Data5 = 5
Data6 = 6
'''.splitlines()[1:]

#Build output data list
outdata = '''
Data1 = 1
Data2 = 2
Data3 = 8
Data4 = 7
'''.splitlines()[1:]

outdict = dict(line.split(' = ') for line in outdata)

for line in defdata:
    key, val = line.split(' = ')
    if key in outdict:
        outval = outdict[key]
        if outval != val:
            print '%s = %s' % (key, outval)
    else:
        print line
```

**output**

```
Data3 = 8
Data4 = 7
Data5 = 5
Data6 = 6
```

---

Here's how to read a text file into a list of lines.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
```

There's also a `.readlines()` method, but it's not so useful here because it preserves the `\n` newline character at the end of each line, and we don't want that.

Note that if there are any blank lines in the text file then the resulting list will have an empty string `''` in that position. Also, that code won't remove any leading or trailing blanks or other whitespace on each line. But if you need to do that there are thousands of examples that can show you how here on Stack Overflow.

---

### Version 2

This new version uses a slightly different approach. 
It loops over a sorted list of all the keys found in either the default list or the output list.
If a key is only found in one of the lists the corresponding line is added to the diff list.
If a key is found in both lists but the output line differs from the default line then the corresponding line from the output list is added to the diff list. If both lines are identical, nothing is added to the diff list.

```
#Build default data list
defdata = '''
Data1 = 1
Data2 = 2
Data3 = 3
Data4 = 4
Data5 = 5
Data6 = 6
'''.splitlines()[1:]

#Build output data list
outdata = '''
Data1 = 1
Data2 = 2
Data3 = 8
Data4 = 7
Data8 = 8
'''.splitlines()[1:]

def make_dict(data):
    return dict((line.split(None, 1)[0], line) for line in data)

defdict = make_dict(defdata)
outdict = make_dict(outdata)

#Create a sorted list containing all the keys
allkeys = sorted(set(defdict) | set(outdict))
#print allkeys

difflines = []
for key in allkeys:
    indef = key in defdict
    inout = key in outdict
    if indef and not inout:
        difflines.append(defdict[key])
    elif inout and not indef:
        difflines.append(outdict[key])
    else:
        #key must be in both dicts
        defval = defdict[key]
        outval = outdict[key]
        if outval != defval:
            difflines.append(outval)

for line in difflines:
    print line
```

**output**

```
Data3 = 8
Data4 = 7
Data5 = 5
Data6 = 6
Data8 = 8
```

Comment: I apologize I'm very new to python I thought i could pass the strings inside my txt document to difflib, as for your code this is a step in the right direction. I'm trying to make it compare data files rather than a list. Would the splitlines() work for opening a text document? for Example: Default = askopenfilename() Then try something like defdata = Default.splitlines()[1:] ?

Comment: What if the output data list has the line `Data8 = 8`?  Shouldn't that be printed too?  It seems to me that the OP wants the symmetric difference, so to speak, of the dicts.  Also, what if the same parameter is configured in two different ways in the output data.  Shouldn't this be flagged?

Comment: @saulspatz Well yes since Data8 = 8 isnt in the default that should be printed as well.

Comment: @JeanP: Sorry, my current code won't print `Data8 = 8` if it's in the output data list but not in the default data list. I didn't realise you wanted that, I was just going from what you have in your example data.

Comment: @JeanP: I'll fix that later - I can't do it now because it's very late in my time zone. But I'll add some code now to show you how to read a text file into a list of lines.

Comment: @PM2Ring Okay that is fine thank you, it's my fault for not being clear in my question.

Comment: @JeanP: Please let me know if my new code does what you need.

Comment: @PM2Ring the new code works fine now its just a matter of me figuring out how to implement File I/O into it. Thank you for the help ill be sure to mark this answer as most helpful