# Compare Entries in a dictionary with a list and print the results

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I have a question about how to go through a dictionary and compare whats inside to a list of parameters.

Lets say i have this dictionary: Lets call this Dictionary `setData[i]`

```
<231931844151>
    Bat: Bat = 10
    Fish: Fish = 16
    Dog: Dog = 5
    Cat: Cat = 4
    Tiger: Tiger = 11
    Bird: Bird = 3

<92103884812>
    Bat: Bat = Null
    Fish: Fish = 24
    Dog: Dog = 10
    Cat: Cat = 40
    Tiger: Tiger = 19
    Bird: Bird = 4
```

This dictionary holds lets called them ID Numbers and those ID Numbers have Data with a parameter, in this case like Bat, Fish, Dog, Cat, Tiger, and Bird.

Now I want to compare this data and it's parameter with a list so i can see if they match correctly.

Our List would be this: Lets call it `defaultData`

```
<ID NUMBER>
Bird = 3
Cat = 40
Dog = 10
Bat = 10
Tiger = 19
Fish = 234
```

So a way of looking at it would be:

[image: Dictionary Compared to a list]
So as we can see the list is compared to each entry in the dictionary and if they're different it will print out which Parameter for which ID is different.

### CODE:

So far I've been thinking of trying out something like the following loop:

```
for k in setData[i]:
        if setData[i] in dataDefault:
            print("If this prints then something Matches")
```

this is just the start of the loop however I appears they do not match or no entry from the List appears in the dictionary. Could it be due to the issue that when creating my dictionary it adds the parameter twice? like in the case of `Bat: Bat = 10` rather than having `Bat = 10` ?

If there is a better method to compare the entries in a Dictionary with a List I would like to know as well

Thank you!

EDIT: ADDED MY DICTIONARY AND LIST:

**Dictionary:**
`[{'Bat': 'Bat = 10', 'Fish': 'Fish = 16', 'Dog': 'Dog = 5', 'Cat': 'Cat = 4', 'Tiger': 'Tiger = 11', 'Bird': 'Bird = 3'}, {'Bat': 'Bat = Null', 'Fish': 'Fish = 24', 'Dog': 'Dog = 10', 'Cat': 'Cat = 40', 'Tiger': 'Tiger = 19', 'Bird': 'Bird = 4'}]`

**List:**
`['<Correct Parameters>', 'Bird: Bird = 3', 'Cat: Cat = 40', 'Dog: Dog = 10', 'Bat: Bat = 10', 'Tiger: Tiger = 19', 'Fish: Fish = 234']`

Current Code: https://dpaste.de/Zvdn

Comment: i think there's something wrong with your dictionaries and lists, can you please post those?

Comment: @le_vine I added an edit with a full copy of my code for creating the Dictionary  and List.

Comment: `[{'Bat': 'Bat = 10', 'Fish': 'Fish = 16', 'Dog': 'Dog = 5', 'Cat': 'Cat = 4', 'Tiger': 'Tiger = 11', 'Bird': 'Bird = 3'}, {'Bat': 'Bat = Null', 'Fish': 'Fish = 24', 'Dog': 'Dog = 10', 'Cat': 'Cat = 40', 'Tiger': 'Tiger = 19', 'Bird': 'Bird = 4'}]
` with out formating this is my dictionary and this is my List: `['<Correct Parameters>', 'Bird: Bird = 3', 'Cat: Cat = 40', 'Dog: Dog = 10', 'Bat: Bat = 10', 'Tiger: Tiger = 19', 'Fish: Fish = 234']
`

Comment: ok, the problem is that you're trying to compare the keys of the dictionaries, that are string like "Bat" with a list of string "Bat: Bat = 10". those strings are not equivalent so it will not print anything in the first loop you've provided

Comment: What would be a way of making that string equivalent? I felt like that was the problem but since I am making a dictionary from a text document that just has the parameter `Bat = 10` It created this entry instead in the dictionary `Bat: Bat = 10`

Comment: that's because you're probably not correctly splitting the line you're reading in the file. it would be useful to look at the code that generates the dictionary and the list

Comment: @le_vine Ill add the code into the oringal post via a dpaste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems seems to come from the format of your data. We should prepare the data to compare it

```
dataDefault = ['<Correct Parameters>', 'Bird: Bird = 3', 'Cat: Cat = 40', 'Dog: Dog = 10', 'Bat: Bat = 10', 'Tiger: Tiger = 19', 'Fish: Fish = 234']
setData = [{'Bat': 'Bat = 10', 'Fish': 'Fish = 16', 'Dog': 'Dog = 5', 'Cat': 'Cat = 4', 'Tiger': 'Tiger = 11', 'Bird': 'Bird = 3'}, {'Bat': 'Bat = Null', 'Fish': 'Fish = 24', 'Dog': 'Dog = 10', 'Cat': 'Cat = 40', 'Tiger': 'Tiger = 19', 'Bird': 'Bird = 4'}]
```

First we change the dataDefault format, by removing everything before ": ":

```
dataDefault2 = []
for i in dataDefault:
    if ": " in i:
        dataDefault2.append(i.split(": ")[1])
    else:
        dataDefault2.append(i)

for elem in setData:  # We iterate over each element of the list
    for val in elem.values() :  # We iterate over each value of the element dictionary
    # If there is any other value which is not a dictionary it will complain with an error
        if val in dataDefault2:
            print("If this prints then something Matches")
```

Comment: trying to split the list with `[i.split(": ")[1] for i in dataDefault]` gives me an out of index error, Ill troubleshoot to see whats causing this

Comment: That's because we have "'<Correct Parameters>'" without ": ". I changed the code

Comment: Okay i magnaged to get it working however it still doesnt match correctly, could it be due to the formating of my dictionary? My dictionary is `[{'Bat': 'Bat = 10', 'Fish': 'Fish = 16', 'Dog': 'Dog = 5', 'Cat': 'Cat = 4', 'Tiger': 'Tiger = 11', 'Bird': 'Bird = 3'}, {'Bat': 'Bat = Null', 'Fish': 'Fish = 24', 'Dog': 'Dog = 10', 'Cat': 'Cat = 40', 'Tiger': 'Tiger = 19', 'Bird': 'Bird = 4'}] ` and since `'Bat': 'Bat = 10'` does not match the list `Bat = 10` it will not print out?

Comment: hold on, I will answer in an hour (or two), I have something else to do :(

Comment: @Llopis: If you're curious about the format of the dictionary (with the keys being repeated in the values), I figured it was a sensible approach in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32076339/4014959), since it meant not having to rebuild the input lines in order to output them.

Comment: I think I don't understand you. The main point of using dictionaries is having a key and a value of that key. Having the key in the value field, doesn't help in any way (AFAIK). It is easier to join the key and the value on user need than using incorrectly the dictionary